# How do I pull last 5 entry from a from a table through SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data entry like below. I want to select the last 5 rows all the time when new data will be inserted. So, product_id 2-6 will be selected in here. But when I will enter a new product, id 3-7 will be selected and afterwards.. What will be SQL query for this? I am newbie. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
product_id   product_name   product_price
------------------------------------------
1            Phone         120
2            Chips         2
3            Television    300
4            PC            400
5            Radio         50
6            Watch         10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below query assuming that "product_id" is incremental as the new rows get added.

**Select * from table_name order by product_id DESC limit 5.**

**Explanation**:
The query will sort the rows based on product_id in descending order and limit 5 will Limit the output to 5 from first row. So even a new row is added the query will give you the last five rows.

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Comment: What if my id is not always sequential? Then what will be the updated query?

Comment: If you can elaborate like which column are you using to track if any new record is entered like a date field then you can sort with respect to that.

Comment: I will be using product_id mainly

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab
ORDER BY product_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the LIMIT keyword, which limits the results of a query to a number of rows. Combining it with the ORDER BY means that it's sorted in the right order.

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY product_id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your IDs are always sequential (no records get deleted) and you insist on having your record sorted in ascending order you can try:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price
FROM table
WHERE product_id > (SELECT MAX(product_id)-5 FROM table);
```

This will work on MySQL